# Using a user-uploaded document to add contect in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, elasticsearch-5

I was wondering whether there is a way I can feed additional text (from a document) to get more accurate results?
For example, a user can upload a PDF that contains text that s/he thinks is relevant to the search. Then use something like TF-IDF to extract important words and feed them to something like a should query along with the actual query in a must query. Has anyone tried something like this? Has it worked? Any better way to achieve this?

I believe it can be done with the More Like This query, but not sure how.

Comment: what is your use case, ideally titles are more useful, so in your case, you can extract the PDF title and store it in different fields and just boost the title field.

Comment: Hi @OpsterElasticsearchNinja
We want to give more context to that search and the title won't cut it. What we want is that the user entered query given the most priority + the selected terms from the PDF if present, gives added weight. Can we achieve this if we put the user query in a ```must``` clause and then all the extra keywords in a ```should``` clasue. What do you think?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja ??